# Invoke Groovy script using Groovy UI button

Tags: swing, groovy

I'm currently building a UI with Groovy Swing builder and I want to call another script on button click.

My code:

```
panel(alignmentX:0f) {
    flowLayout(alignment:FL.LEFT)
    button('Import KM', actionPerformed: {
    vars.dialogResult = 'Import KM'
    gshell.evaluate(new File("ImportKnowledgeModules.groovy")) 
})
```

The new script is also in the same directory as the calling script. But nothing happens when I click the button 'Import KM'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Take in account that the second script path must be relative to the path where you runs `groovy` command not to the path of your UI groovy script.

Example: I take the original code from http://groovy-lang.org/swing.html and I save it as `swing.groovy`, then I change the click me `button` to call `swing.groovy` itself using [`groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(java.io.File)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html#evaluate(java.io.File)) as you do. So finally I have the follow code in `swing.groovy`:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell

count = 0
new SwingBuilder().edt {
  frame(title: 'Frame', size: [300, 300], show: true) {
    borderLayout()
    textlabel = label(text: 'Click the button!', constraints: BL.NORTH)
    button(text:'Click Me',
         actionPerformed: {
             println "click :P"
             new GroovyShell().evaluate(new File('swing.groovy'))    
         }, constraints:BL.SOUTH)
  }
}
```

If I run `groovy swing.groovy` the button evaluates correctly the script and the UI appears recursively. However if I run groovy from another path like `groovy ./Scripts/swing.groovy` then I have to change the path to `new GroovyShell().evaluate(new File('./Scripts/swing.groovy'))` from my code in order to reference it correctly.

Hope it helps,